# Where can I find the source code for TempleOS?

Tags: repository, open-source, source-code, templeos

From a Reddit post, TempleOS creator [Terry Davis seems to have had a repository on his website](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/3izi4y/proof_that_templeos_is_100_open_source/cul5fyb/)

> People don't believe I wrote my own compiler.
>
> All the source code is on all the distros and on my website.
>
> ```
> http://www.templeos.org/Wb/Home/Wb2/LineRep.html#l519
> http://www.templeos.org/Wb/Home/Wb2/SymsAlpha.html
> http://www.templeos.org/Wb/
> ```

But, None of those links are still active. Has the source repository moved? Is there a public repository of the TempleOS source code? If it's open source, is the code included in the distribution? Ideally, I would get a git/cvs/svn repo though. Does Terry develop anywhere publicly, or just save locally and publish the source code in the ISOs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TempleOS is not known to be officially hosted in any repository. However, every binary file is just source that's [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation)-compiled when you run it.

To edit code you can use `Ed("~/file.HC.Z")`, and to see it [(the Linux equivalent of `cat` you can use `Type("~/file.HC.Z")`](https://superuser.com/q/1328371/11116)

Further HTML docs generated from the TempleOS 5.03 source code can be found here:

- https://templeos.holyc.xyz/Wb/Home/Web/LineRep.html
- https://templeos.holyc.xyz/Wb/Home/Web/SymsAlpha.html
- https://templeos.holyc.xyz/Wb/