# What is the Unix equivalent of `cat` for TempleOS?

Tags: shell, cat, templeos

If I want to `cat` or a list the contents of a file on the page, what is the TempleOS-equivalent of that command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TempleOS equivalent of `cat` is `Type`. To see `~/Registry.HC.Z`, you can run

```
Type("~/Registry.HC.Z");
```